# WatchViewStub Deprecated

Tags: android, wear-os

I started doing a Wearable app and I can see in my `MainActivity` that the `WatchViewStub` is deprecated. I've searched online what should I use instead of the `WatchViewStub` but I can't find anything. I use `support:wearable:2.0.0-alpha3'`. Anyone who could help?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to check this [blog](https://sterlingudell.wordpress.com/category/wearables/), which will tell a workaround with `WatchViewStub`. You can try [`onApplyWindowInsets`](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html#ScreenShape), which can easily get the screen shape there – and inflate the proper layout accordingly. Also, you can check this [git](https://gist.github.com/tajchert/a49c22f54962bd9005bc) for code implementation purposes. This git show how screen shape detection on Android Wear Devices. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an Android Developer's blog on the topic. `BoxInsetLayout` and the new `-round` resource qualifier are a few options.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/build-beautifully-for-android-wear.html